# Simplifying expression with definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I don't know where to start?

 How can I simplify this problem? (what are the steps to simplify this problem)

Simplify the following expression

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{-(x^2)}^{x^3}(\frac{sin(t)}{(1+cos(t))}+1)dt+\int_{x^3}^{x^2}(\frac{sin(t)}{(1+cos(t))}-1)\,dt\right)$$

with ($-1\le x \le 1$).

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus, and chain rule.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 0):

Take
$$f(t)=\frac{sin(t)}{1+cos(t)} +1$$
$$=>f(-t)=-\frac{sin(t)}{1+cos(t)}+1$$
$$=>f(t)+f(-t)=2$$
Now the expression becomes
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{-x^2}^{x^3}f(t)dt+\int_{x^3}^{x^2} (f(t)-2)dt\right)$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{-x^2}^{x^3}f(t)dt+\int_{x^3}^{x^2}f(t)dt-2\int_{x^3}^{x^2}dt\right)$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{-x^2}^{x^2}f(t)dt+2\int_{x^2}^{x^3}dt\right)$$
Now use the property of definite integral:
$$\int_{-a}^{a}f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{a}(f(t)+f(-t))dt$$
$$=>\int_{-x^2}^{x^2}f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{x^2}2dt$$
Hence
$$\frac{d}{dx}2\left(\int_{0}^{x^2}dt+\int_{x^2}^{x^3}dt\right)$$
$$=2\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{0}^{x^3}dt\right)$$
$$=2\frac{d}{dx}(x^3)$$
$$=6x^2$$
See also Leibniz integral rule